# Confusion About z-index

Tags: html, css

The article in the following link states that z-index stacking is only applicable to sibling elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

But the below snippet shows that divs that have different parents are stacked with regard to the z-index. Overlay stays over the text and below the textbox even though both the text and textbox belong to the same parent but not the overlay. How is that possible according to the article?

```css
.overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay" style="display: block;"></div>

<div>
    <div>
    Some text that will remain under the overlay.
    </div>
    <div style="width:1000px;">
        <div style="width:50%;position:relative;z-index:2;">
            <div>
                <input style="width:80%;">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Good question. I think it has something to do with your use of position fixed and position relative.

Comment: where does it state it would only be possible between siblings?

Comment: @webeno "Importantly, the z-index values of its child stacking contexts only have meaning in this parent. Stacking contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent stacking context."

Comment: @webeno "Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings: only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed."

Comment: none of these mean "that z-index stacking is only applicable to sibling elements", you are misunderstanding the doc...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your z-index comparison starts from the first `relative` or `absolute` positioned DOM element. So  basically css z-index ignores all elements that have `static` position.

```
 <div class="overlay" style="display: block;"></div>

<div style="position:relative;z-index:3;">
    <div>
    Some text that will remain under the overlay.
    </div>
    <div style="width:1000px;">
        <div style="width:50%;">
            <div>
                <input style="width:80%;">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I think this should work for you

Answer (score -1):

The documentation reads:

> Each stacking context is completely independent from its siblings:
>   only descendant elements are considered when stacking is processed.

This does not mean that the stacking context **element** itself is independent from its siblings, but this means that the children are.

Note that stacking contexts live within 'positioned elements'. Positioned elements are elements with position 'relative', 'absolute' or 'fixed' and a z-index. Only positioned elements get stacked. In this case there are only two positioned elements. They are stacking contexts themselves, as is their nearest positioned ancestor. These items, however, do not seem to have a (shared) positioned ancestor. Based on this, we can say the following:

*These items both belong to the same positioned ancestor (stacking context): the viewport. Therefore the z-indexes give you expected results (higher z-index means on top). Equal z-index appear in the reading order (last one on top).*

Creating another positioned ancestor breaks this behaviour, as Leonid shows. This happens because this creates a new **independent** stacking context.

Adding opacity to the second div also breaks this behaviour, as elements that need to be redrawn are (strangely enough) handled as positioned elements (new stacking contexts):

```
<div class="overlay" style="display: block;"></div>
<div style="opacity: 0.99;">...</div>
```

See this in action: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENrOGx

---

**Still don't get it?**

Read Philip Waltons article: https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/. He explains it really well.

PS. Who does not like a good STACKING question on STACK overflow?